# I couldn't update on Debian 10 using sudo apt update

Tags: debian, updates, apt, debian-buster

```
Hit:1 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/Debian_10  InRelease
Ign:2 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/Debian Buster InRelease
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease [65.4 kB]
Get:4 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian buster InRelease [121 kB]                  
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease                                               
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY AA8E81B4331F7F50 NO_PUBKEY 112695A0E562B32A
Err:5 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/Debian Buster Release                               
  404  Not Found [IP: 195.135.221.134 80]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease [49.3 kB]                                              
Err:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease                                    
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 04EE7237B7D453EC NO_PUBKEY 648ACFD622F3D138
Err:4 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian buster InRelease                                                                                                                                            
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 04EE7237B7D453EC NO_PUBKEY 648ACFD622F3D138 NO_PUBKEY DCC9EFBF77E11517
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                                                     
W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY AA8E81B4331F7F50 NO_PUBKEY 112695A0E562B32A
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/Debian Buster Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 04EE7237B7D453EC NO_PUBKEY 648ACFD622F3D138
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian buster InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 04EE7237B7D453EC NO_PUBKEY 648ACFD622F3D138 NO_PUBKEY DCC9EFBF77E11517
E: The repository 'http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian buster InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: How `download.opensuse.org` got into apt sources?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

```
$ sudo -s
# junk=$(grep -l opensuse /etc/apt/source.list /etc/apt/source.list.d/*)
# mv "$junk" "${junk}.bak"
# apt update
# apt upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, one openSUSE repository does not exist. But this only applies to `http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/Debian` while the second one does: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/

So you might want to check and fix your list files `/etc/apt/source.list` and `/etc/apt/source.list.d/*.list` more careful instead of following the suggested hammer method ;). Whether this repo is useful for you or not is a different question.

#### But there is another issue:

```
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease                                               
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY AA8E81B4331F7F50 NO_PUBKEY 112695A0E562B32A
```

This likely means that you didn't add the public Debian repository key/keyring to you trusted repository keys. The easiest way is probably to manually install/update the official keyring package:

```
cd /tmp
wget https://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/debian-archive-keyring/debian-archive-keyring_2019.1_all.deb
dpkg -i debian-archive-keyring_2019.1_all.deb
rm debian-archive-keyring_2019.1_all.deb
```

This is part of the repository itself hence will be kept up-to-date when applying `apt-get upgrade`. **For future readers, if the above package does not exist anymore, or you use a different Debian version, check out the following for the current keyring package for your Debian version: https://packages.debian.org/debian-archive-keyring**